# A patent issued as another patent?

Tags: patent-applications, software, patent-search, google-patents

In [this answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/24984/27973), George wrote

> It has been issued (Jan. 2022) in the US as Suggested functions for
> formulas in spreadsheets US 11227106B2 but is still pending in Europe
> as of October 12 2022.

where I think "It" referred to [the patent (US10853732B2)](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10853732B2/en?oq=US2018005122) mentioned in the question.

I don't understand what "has been issued (Jan. 2022) in the US as .... US 11227106B2" mean. Does it mean the patent US10853732B2 did not exist in the US anymore?

How could we observe this from patents.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the confusion was generated but the first question was about a PCT application [WO2020190548A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2020190548A1/en?oq=WO2020190548A1).

That is the “it” I was responding to. A PCT application is a bundle of 140+ applications in so many places. At some point the branches of the PCT die if they are not “entered into the national stage”. The MS application was entered into the national stage in the US and in the EPO. You can see this by following the Global Dossier link in google patents. The U.S. version became or led to two applications 16/521295 and 16/521397. Each was published (under publication numbers).

The first was granted as US [11227106](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11227106B2/en?oq=11227106) and the second as US [11080477](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11080477B2/en?oq=11080477).

The start of tracking it via the Goblal Dossier in a screenshot—

[image]

The EPO also has two applications pending that are derived from the original PCT application.

US [US10853732B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10853732B2/en?oq=US10853732B2) is an unrelated patent in the same topic area with different but overlapping inventors that was filed a few years earlier by MS.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The link in [my previous question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/24983/27973) was indeed https://patents.google.com/patent/US10853732B2/en?oq=US2018005122. It was unrelated to WO2020190548A1 or US11227106B2.

Comment: You linked to the PCT application in the first question in your series of questions. Sorry, I thought that was still the topic in the second question without reading carefully. Bottom line - Both MS the 2016 and 2019 applications have issued patents and if you sell something you think falls under the claims of any of them you might need more help than SE can provide.